# Is there any way to define controllers in gate definitions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I am setting up a new project and I want to use gates and policies. I know how to use it by Laravel documentation but I want to go furthermore.

We have a boot method in AuthServiceProvider where we should define gates and policies.

Can we define controllers in gates something like this?

```
Gate::define(SomeController::class, function ($user) {
   if($user->something) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to protect specific routes (prevent unauthorized users from hitting your controllers), **middleware** is your best option. Gates/Policies are there to protect models/actions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user->something) {
            return false;
       }

       return true;
    }
}
```

More details on how to create and register middleware here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware